# Why isn't my error being caught?

Tags: c#, error-handling

I have a class which contains a **Phone** object.

The phone is a virtual phone, and in the constructor to my class, I pass in the IP Address and the port of the virtual phone I wish to connect to.

Inside the constructor, I then run a method called **Connect**. In the **Connect** method I instantiate an **IPEndPoint** object out of the IP Address/Port combo of the phone, I then instantiate a **Socket** object, and run the **Connect** method of the **Socket** object, passing in my **IPEndPoint** as the parameter.

If the phone server hasn't been configured properly for a particular phone (not my job) the connection is refused, and a **SocketException** is thrown. I am trying to catch this exception.

This is a Windows Form application. Within the scope of the Form object, but outside of the scope of any constructors/methods, I have my phone as an uninstantiated private field like so (IPhone is the interface which my phone uses):

```
private IPhone _phone;
```

I have a method called **SetupPhone**, I instantiate my phone object in here, and am trying to catch the exception here:

```
private void SetupPhone()
{
    try
    {
        _phone = new Phone(AgentDetails.IPAddress, AgentDetails.Port);
    }
    catch(SocketException ex)
    {
        Log.LogException("Error mapping phone to port", ex);
        ShowBaloonTip("An error occured starting CTI. Please select your name from the list to try again", ToolTipIcon.Error);

        ChangeUser();
        return;
    }

    //Subscribe to Phone events here
}
```

Here's the constructor for the phone object:

```
public Phone(string ipAddress, int port, string password = "FooBar")
{
    Connect(ipAddress, port, password);
}
```

Here is the Connect method:

```
public void Connect(string ipAddress, int port, string password)
{
    _phone = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port);
    _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

    _socket.Connect(_phone);

    //Redacted
}
```

On a not properly configured phone, my SocketException is thrown as shown below:

[image: Exception]

Am I not right in thinking that any exceptions thrown by any methods run in an objects constructor should be safely caught by a try/catch block put around the instantiation of that object? Or is this not the case? I want to catch any errors that may occur when instantiating my object, is this not possible?

Comment: Have you tried just catching Exception to see what happens?

Comment: @activwerx Yes, I have tried catching Exception, same thing happens.

Comment: are you handling exceptions elsewhere? maybe its being caught at a higher level or something?

Comment: Nesim solved it, I changed my VS Exception settings a while ago so I could debug exceptions thrown on other threads, and this is what is causing my issue now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSBreakOnException.aspx

> When running a program in debug mode, using Visual Studio's debugger,
>   and encountering an exception, the default behaviour is to pause
>   execution unless the error is handled in a try / catch block. This
>   behaviour can be modified for each exception type.

**Debug Mode Exceptions**

> When you execute your software in debug mode, Visual Studio reacts
>   differently to a thrown exception depending upon whether the exception
>   is handled within a try / catch / finally block or is unhandled. When
>   using the default configuration, unhandled exceptions cause the
>   program to halt and the exception details to be displayed. Handled
>   exceptions do not cause the program to stop. You can see this by
>   executing the following code in debug mode. Although a
>   DivideByZeroException is thrown when the division is attempted, the
>   program continues. If you comment out the try and catch, the exception
>   halts execution.

```
try
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    Console.WriteLine(j / i);
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Caught an exception");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

> This behaviour is useful in most circumstances. However, sometimes you
>   will want to ignore a specific type of exception, even when unhandled,
>   or break on a handled exception that would normally be ignored. You
>   can control this using the Exceptions dialog box, which may be viewed
>   by selecting "Exceptions" from the Debug menu or by pressing
>   Ctrl-Alt-E.
>
> The main area of the dialog box shows a list of exception types in a
>   tree structure. The branches of the tree can be expanded to show
>   various groups of exceptions and the individual types within each
>   category. Two checkboxes are shown for each exception and group. If
>   the "Thrown" checkbox is ticked, the program will break when the
>   selected exception, or one of the selected group of exceptions, is
>   encountered. This includes exceptions that have been handled. If the
>   "User-unhandled" checkbox is ticked the program will break only if the
>   exception is unhandled. To try the options, find the
>   DivideByZeroException type in the tree structure. To find an exception
>   quickly, click the Find button and enter part of the name of the item
>   you are searching for. The first matching item will be found. If this
>   is not the desired exception, click the Find Next button to cycle
>   through the matches. Once you have found DivideByZeroException, check
>   the appropriate "Thrown" option. If you run the sample program you
>   will see that the program halts on the handled exception.

**Reset All**

> There are some further options in the Exceptions dialog box that are
>   worthy of note. The first of these is the Reset All button. If you
>   have changed the options in the dialog box to help debug your
>   application, you can reset all of the options to their original
>   settings by clicking this button.

**Configuring Custom Exceptions**

> If you have defined your own exception type that inherits
>   functionality from the Exception class or one of its subclasses, you
>   may wish to configure it using the dialog box. As it will not be a
>   standard exception type, it will not appear in the list by default.
>   However, you can add it by clicking the Add button and providing the
>   details. For .NET exceptions you should ensure that you choose the
>   "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" option from the drop-down list.
>   You should then provide the fully qualified name of the exception
>   class. For example, "MyNamespace.MyException".

Comment: Thankyou Nesim! I changed my VS Exception settings a while ago as I was having trouble catching Exceptions thrown on other threads. This is what was causing my issue now. Changed them back and my program is working as expected.